# Mini-cart not showing products added

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, magento2.3.6-p1

I'm developing a Magento 2.3.6-p1 store, using a based luma custom theme, and mini-cart **is not showing** added products, it **ONLY** shows the products when i add a product, but when i reload the page, the mini-cart says it's empty. Only will show the products if i add another one.

**Things i tried:** full page cache is already on.
[image: admin full page cache]

Sometimes when i try to add a product, it shows an error message: "your session expired".

**Plus error:** the mini-cart doesn't remove items when i click on the trash icon.

**Plus information:** when i reload the page, the mini-cart loses its items, just shows it again when another item is added.

**Update:** Tried change base url: `bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://gatomia.local/ --base-url-secure=https://gatomia.local/`  but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a website URL that is not showing added products in the cart?

Comment: It's only in local environment, but its http://gatomia.local/produto-teste.html

Comment: Is there any error in console?.

Comment: No, the only error i got on log files is: "Reference to undeclared plugin with name 'priceIndexUpdater' "